# Basic jump issue in Godot engine

Tags: godot, 2d-games, gdscript

Hello all and sorry if the question is too basic.

I'm trying to create a basic jump. The point is that it works fine when y press jump + lateral mov, but it goes to the top and beyond when I press just the jump button. Here is the code. I'd appreciate any help:

BTW: Code is for 2D and in Godot 4.0

```
const GRAVITY = 10
const JUMP_FORCE = 100.0
var time_gravity = 0

var screen_size # Size of the game window.
var velocity  # the area's velocity
var is_on_floor = true

func _ready():
    screen_size = get_viewport_rect().size
    var pos = Vector2(init_pos_x,init_pos_y)
    start(pos)

func _process(delta):
    if is_on_floor:
        velocity = Vector2.ZERO # Set the player's movement vector to (0,0)

    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
        velocity.x += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
        velocity.x -= 1
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump"):
        if is_on_floor:
            is_on_floor = false
            velocity.y = (-1) * JUMP_FORCE 
    if !is_on_floor:
        if position.y > init_pos_y:
            is_on_floor = true
            velocity.y = 0
            position.y = init_pos_y
            time_on_jump = 0
        else:
            time_on_jump += delta
            velocity.y += GRAVITY * time_on_jump

    if velocity.length() > 0:
        velocity = velocity.normalized() * move_speed
        $AnimatedSprite2D.flip_h = velocity.x < 0
        $AnimatedSprite2D.play("run")
    else:
        $AnimatedSprite2D.play("idle")
        
    position.x += velocity.x * delta
    position.y += velocity.y * delta
    print_debug("Position: ", position, " Delta: ", delta)
    position.x = clamp(position.x, 0, screen_size.x)
    position.y = clamp(position.y, 0, screen_size.y)
```

Comment: I don't know about the particular issue. I might need to see the full code to be sure. However, it seems you are using an `Area2D` where a `CharacterBody2D` would serve you better. Also the gravity logic does not look right (you don't need to accumulate time for it). But that does not explain why it would only work when the player is going to the sides.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Ive just solve it. It was a matter of scales... jump_force it was very small compared to speed. Changing the jump_force to 400 it works as expected.